# Synchronize folder on Windows/Mac (in realtime not with a scheduler)

Tags: windows, mac, sync

Probably this question is not new and if yes, sorry for the repost.

But I need to synchronize a local folder onto a Windows machine (or Mac) with the content into a remote folder (WebDav resource).

This sync should be in realtime (like dropbox).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well depends what you understand under realtime.

If your setup is not too complicated you can achieve this with Rsync. You can get it for both machines and then have it run periodically.

For more complex setups you may be able to put together something through a version control system like svn - but that's real work.

Comment: As "realtime" I mean something that synchronize files when they change.

Comment: Perfect realtime is never possible. My point is if it takes you 30min to transfer you files the closest to realtime you get is that the files on the other side will be there in 30minutes.

Comment: Probably in your case we are talking about seconds. But if it's essential to have the synchronization in -say - a second it gets complicated with this approach.

Comment: to be more clear, I would like something like dropbox synchronization but I don't want to store my data into the cloud :-)

Comment: who doesn't :D If you can set up a server maybe try the suggestions from the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard about dropbox alternatives that allow you to use your own server. [teamdrive](http://www.teamdrive.com/) and [sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/) would be two. Last time I checked they were very new and seemed alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Try Livemesh.  It does offline synchronization.

**edit**

It doesn't have to use Skydrive.  It's not like dropbox. It can also do P2P synch.

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-sync-p2p-using

Comment: But it seems to me that livemesh uses Skydrive as sync remote drive. Isn't it?

Comment: Live mesh also has a peer to peer mode.